# lambda.min in lasso for correlated variable selection

Tags: r, lasso, glmnet

Lasso uses cross-validation to determine both the number of included predictors and the degree of shrinkage to avoid over-fitting. I have used the glmnet package to do this.

```
    fit=glmnet(x,y)
    cvob1= cv.glmnet(x,y) 
    lambda1=cvob1$lambda.min  
    cvob2=cv.glmnet(x,y)
    lambda2=cvob2$lambda.min
```

There is a high possibility that lambda1 and lambda2 are different. I need to get a proper lambda.min for the next step to obtain fitted values for the sparse solution to the model:

```
coef(fit,s=cvob1$lambda.min)
```

How can I decide which lambda to use? Should I repeat the cv.glmnet() for many times? How many time should I go for?

Comment: You have to run cv.glmnet many times, follow the below answer: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/97777/variablity-in-cv-glmnet-results/173895#173895

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CV is a random process, which is why you are getting different `lambda.min`s.  But they *should* be close to eachother.  If you want a singular, reproducible lambda, try setting a seed:

`set.seed(1234)`

Comment: would different lambdas affect my next step: coef(fit,s=cvob1$lambda.min)

Comment: Yes, since different lambdas would yield different coefficients.  (Remember large $\lambda$, small $\|\beta\|$).

Comment: setting a seed for cv.glmnet won't produce identical results unless the foldid's are set manually