# ElasticNet coefficients are different for each cv.glmnet run

Tags: regression, cross-validation, glmnet

I am new to R and `cv.glmnet`. I have now tried to run my logistic model with ElasticNet instead of stepwise as people in this community suggest. But, I have troubles with the model itself as it keeps giving me different end results. I want to get `alpha` and `lambda` by letting `cv.glmnet` do this through minimization with a `k-fold` of 10. I learnt to set `foldid` equal to something in order to leave out the randomness in the `coefficients`, but I still get this randomness in my `coefficients` in the end of each run. All other answers to this question deals with a fixed `alpha` as [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/478924/different-outcome-of-cv-glmnet-coefficients) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/97777/variablity-in-cv-glmnet-results). This is my code

```
set.seed(123)
nfolds <- 10
foldid <- sample(1:10, size = length(y), replace=TRUE)
model <- lapply(1:10, function(i){
      cv.glmnet(trainX, trainY, type.measure = "deviance", family = "binomial", alpha = i, foldid = foldid, parallel = TRUE)
 })
```

Again, I do not want to fix my `alpha` and `lambda`, but surely get consistent `coefficients` when I run my Elastic model again and again. Can someone please tell me, what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Perhaps I’ve missed something, but of course you get different coefficients each time. You’re fitting to different data.

Comment: I am fitting my `trainX` and `trainY` everytime I run it?

Comment: It’s selecting different folds each time.

Comment: But by setting `foldid` to something fixed, I would diminish that according to [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/103144/292348).